# How export sheets to pdf and upload it in one specific folder?

Tags: node.js, pdf, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to convert one google sheet into a pdf file. Actually, that, seems ok. But i can't put it directly in one specifics folder ...

Can you help me ?

```
const getData = await getSpreadSheetData(newSpreadsheetsId);
if (!getData) {
    // nop
    return;
}

let url = getData.data.spreadsheetUrl;
if (!url) {
    // nop
    return
}
url = url.replace(/edit$/, '');
const url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&portrait=true'
url = url + url_ext;
const dest = fs.createWriteStream('test.pdf');
await g.drive.files.export(
  {
    fileId: `${newSpreadsheetsId}`,  // Please set the file ID of Google Docs.
    mimeType: "application/pdf"
  },
  { responseType: "stream" },function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    if (!response) {
        // nop
        return
    }
    response.data
      .on("end", function() {
        console.log("Done.");
      })
      .on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("Error during download", err);
        return process.exit();
      })
      .pipe(dest);
  })
```

getSpreadSheetData retrieve me all the data from one spreadsheetID
I'm not an expert with pipe etc ...
I have trying some options like this link :
[Github - google Drive export pdf in Landscape](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1622)
And i don't want this file on my server, or transiting by my server ... :/

Answer (score 2):

after few hours there is the solution :

g = auth

```
    const exportAsPdfInFolder = await g.drive.files.export(
    {
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',
        alt: 'media',
    },
    { responseType: 'stream' },
    async (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            const media = {
                mimeType: 'application/pdf',
                body: result?.data,
            };
            await g.drive.files.create(
                {
                    requestBody: {
                        name: newTitlePDF,
                        parents: [folderParentId],
                    },
                    media: media,
                    fields: 'id',
                },
                async (err: any, file: any) => {
                    if (err) {
                        // Handle error
                        console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
                    }
                },
            );
        }
    },
);
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)